# Por que a pesquisa da página 'Fazer uma pergunta' é melhor que a pesquisa normal do site?

Tags: suporte, pesquisa

Quando você está na página de criação de uma nova pergunta, enquanto você digita o título, o site sugere possíveis perguntas similares que já foram feitas.

Exemplo: `Quais as opções para desenvolvimento de apps para smartphones`

[image: Sugestões de perguntas similares, ao formular uma nova pergunta]

Mas quando pesquisamos exatamente o mesmo texto na pesquisa normal do site, a quantidade de perguntas encontradas é **muito** menor (e diferente, inclusive):

[image: Resultado de pesquisa com mesmos termos]

O que é bem ruim, porque você procura um assunto, não acha, aí decide perguntar por aquilo, elabora um texto para a pergunta na cabeça, avalia se está bom para se perguntar por aqui, e aí quando vai redigir o texto... descobre que já existem várias perguntas similares.

Alguém sabe porque isso acontece, se é um bug conhecido ou se estou fazendo algo errado?

Comment: É que você não pesquisou pelo Google ainda :D Eu acho que é porque o seu texto acaba dando mais contexto pra achar.

Comment: Acredito que na página de pesquisa a busca tende a ser mais exata, e na de perguntar, mais abrangente

Comment: @Maniero, verdade, acho que eu usei uma ou duas vezes a pesquisa do SO, em 99% dos casos chego nas perguntas do SO pelo Google mesmo, hehe... Mas, seria interessante que o resultado das duas fosse coerente, não? Ou que pelo menos a pesquisa normal trouxesse mais resultados, porque obviamente há muito mais do que foi exibido...

Comment: Ela é mais "variada" apenas, mas não é melhor não, tem muita coisa que só acha na outra. E ambas são péssimas em termos de contexto (principalmente se as palavras chave estiverem divididas entre pergunta e resposta). Pior é a falta de busca por caracteres especiais, o que é absurdo não funcionar num site de programação. A busca está nas minhas "top 5 coisas fundamentais do site que não funcionam corretamente".

Comment: Entendi @Bacco, então a melhor coisa a fazer é aceitar a realidade como ela é e continuar pesquisando pelo Google, não é? ;-)

Comment: @PedroGaspar se dependesse de mim a melhor coisa seria por um sistema decente e unificado, mas eu não tenho acesso a isso.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>Roubado</strike> Traduzido [daqui](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/20434/208518):

> - Quando uso a pesquisa, escrevo umas quantas palavras-chave, algumas coisas que possam ter que ver com o que estou à procura.
> - Quando uso o campo do título da pergunta, eu *escrevo uma pergunta* mesmo, portanto penso mesmo sobre como compor isto enquanto uma pergunta.
>
> Acho que esta é a razão para os (aparentemente) melhores resultados: pomos a pesquisa de modos diferentes.

Um pequeno aparte: fizemos algumas alterações à pesquisa que acontece na página "faça uma pergunta" recentemente, de modo a que os resultados apresentados aí sejam mais relevantes, e apareçam mais rapidamente — como resultado, vimos uma subida no número de utilizadores que carregam nesses resultados!

Comment: Mas o que esse usuário sugeriu é que pensamos diferente na hora de pesquisar e de fazer uma pergunta, e, portanto, escrevemos as frases de formas diferentes nos dois contextos (pelo menos foi o que entendi), entretanto, como eu mostrei na pergunta, se você escrever exatamente a mesma sentença, sem tirar nem por nenhum caractere, o resultado é **muito** diferente nos dois contextos. E, sim, o resultado da página "faça uma pergunta" é muito melhor! Mas, ao meu ver, o resultado da página de pesquisa deveria ser tão bom quanto, ou até melhor, já que é uma ferramenta específica para isso.

Comment: O resultado da página "faça uma pergunta," como diz [uma outra resposta na mesma pergunta lá no MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/27187/208518), está estritamente a pesquisar títulos de perguntas — o que quer dizer que vai tentar procurar **frases** semelhantes ao título que estamos a sugerir. A pesquisa normal, por outro lado, vai olhar para tags, perguntas, respostas, títulos, e corpos de publicações — a pesquisa aqui é mais feita com palavras chave do que frases completas. Se incluíssemos todos os resultados da outra pesquisa nesta, havia muito "barulho" nos resultados.

Comment: Verdade, é capaz que viesse muito "lixo" no resultado se incluísse tudo.... Mas o problema é que, o jeito que está, o resultado da página de pesquisa é muito "pobre", e aí acaba desestimulando os usuários de procurar algo por lá, creio eu.

Comment: Eu tentei usar o comando `title:` na caixa da página de pesquisa, mas não consegui fazer funcionar de nenhum jeito...

Comment: Mm.... também não tou a conseguir fazer o `title:` funcionar... E sim, tens razão que pelo menos alguns dos títutlos talvez pudessem aparecer na pesquisa. Vou ver internamente se há alguma coisa que se possa fazer ;)